# How to get geospatial POINT using SparkSQL

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm converting a process from postgreSQL over to DataBrick ApacheSpark,

The postgresql process uses the following sql function to get the point on a map from a X and Y value. *ST_Transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(x, y),4326),3857)*

Does anyone know how I can achieve this same logic in SparkSQL o databricks?

Comment: You will probably have to replace PostGIS with another librarby. [This link](https://databricks.com/de/session_na20/geospatial-options-in-apache-spark) is a good starting point for your research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use some library, like, [Apache Sedona](https://sedona.apache.org/), [GeoMesa](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/tutorials/spark.html), or something else.  Sedona, for example, has the [ST_TRANSFORM](https://sedona.apache.org/api/sql/Function/#st_transform) function, maybe it has the rest as well.

The only thing that you need to take care, is that if you're using pure SQL, then on Databricks you will need:

- install Sedona libraries using the [init script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/init-scripts), so libraries should be there before Spark starts
- set Spark configuration parameters, as described in the following [pull request](https://github.com/apache/incubator-sedona/pull/513)

Update June 2022nd: people at Databricks developed the [Mosaic library](https://github.com/databrickslabs/mosaic/) that is heavily optimized for geospatial analysis on Databricks, and it's compatible with standard `ST_` functions.